# C# median value among group calculation

Tags: c#, linq, median

I have to calculate the median for a group of values in one of my C# function. I have used the formula from the site, [mathisfun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html). Following is my data model and the code.

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Group { get; set; }

    public long? Population { get; set; }
}
```

Sample dataList is as follows,

```
> dataList Count = 7
>     [0]: {DataModel}
>       Group: "16 to 24"       Population: 39657245
>     [1]: {DataModel}      Group: "25 to 34"       Population: 58957845
>     [2]: {DataModel}      Group: "35 to 44"       Population: 12557845
>     [3]: {DataModel}      Group: "45 to 54"       Population: 25698746
>     [4]: {DataModel}      Group: "55 to 64"       Population: 325487
```

Following is the function logic which takes the dataList as a input and returns the median value as output.

```
public int CalculateMedianAge(IList<DataModel> dataList)
        {
            int median = 0;
            var sum = 0;
            var sumRange = 0;
            DataModel medianGroup = new DataModel();

            foreach (var item in dataList)
            {               
                    sum = sum + (int)item.Population;               
            }
            int range = (sum + 1) / 2;          
            foreach(var entry in dataList)
            {
                sumRange = sumRange + (int)entry.Population;
                if (range > sumRange)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    medianGroup = entry;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var lowerBoundary = int.Parse(medianGroup.Group.Split(' ')[0]) - 0.5;
            var cumulativeFrequency = 0;
            for (int s = 0; s< dataList.IndexOf(medianGroup); s++)
            {
                cumulativeFrequency = cumulativeFrequency + (int)dataList[s].Population;
            }           
            var width = int.Parse(medianGroup.Group.Split(' ')[2]) - int.Parse(medianGroup.Group.Split(' ')[0]);

            //L is the lower class boundary of the group containing the median - lowerBoundary
            //n is the total number of values - sum
            //B is the cumulative frequency of the groups before the median group - cumulativeFrequency
            //G is the frequency of the median group - (int)lowerBoundary.Population
            //w is the group width - width
            //MedianAge = L + (((n/2) - B) / G) * W

            median = (int)(lowerBoundary + (((sum/2) - cumulativeFrequency) / (int)medianGroup.Population) * width);

            return median;
        }
```

It is working fine and I can able to get the median value as well. But I am trying to re-factor it with LINQ. I don't want to keep it with Continue and Break statements.

Can anyone suggest/re-factor the above?

Comment: I think if you can't write code it linq (or even you can but it's hard for you), leave it in foreach. Linq will be harder to understand and debug for you and others

Comment: If you want to use linq check out `.Sum()` and `.Max()`.

Comment: This could be a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don't really need the continue statement in your loop - change if statement to _"if (range <= sumRange) { medianGroup = entry; break; }"_

Answer (score 1):

This definitely looks bad:

```
 var population = dataList.Sum(x => x.pop);
 var aggregate = 0;
 var median = dataList
     .Select(x => new
     {
         split = x.Group.Split(" to "),
         pop   = (int)x.Population
     })
     .Select(x => new
     {
         from = int.Parse(x.split[0]),
         to   = int.Parse(x.split[1]),
         x.pop
     })
     //median calculation here VVVV
     .SelectMany(x=> 
         Enumerable
             .Range(x.from, x.to - x.from + 1)
             .Select(y=> new
             {
                 age = y,
                 pop = x.pop/(x.to - x.from + 1) //tail lost here, for small values will return incorrect values. Distribution through linq is bad idea here.
             })
      )
     .OrderBy(x => x.age)
     .First(x => (aggregate+= x.pop) >= population/2)
     .age;
```

**PS**: Not tested this. Your approach through **for** is good. Linq is bad to use here.